# Magento 2 Add custom attribute on order PDF Print All action Drop down

Tags: magento2.2.2, pdf, print

In admin orders how to include custom attribute on pdf print all action?

[image]

It spits out PDF with Products SKU Price Qty Tax Subtotal I need to add another which is warehouse_location I know to add label is ../../../vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

How to add the values?

Comment: I've implemented the code standing above. I uploaded the new DefaultInvoice.php file to the FTP, refreshed the cache but it still doens't works. On the invoice isn't coming a 'locatiecode' field, also no title in de titlebar (i mean the bar where the names 'Products, SKU, price, QTY' are). I hope someone can help me out. This is (a part of) my code: public function draw() { $order = $this->getOrder(); $item = $this->getItem(); $pdf = $this->getPdf(); $page = $this->getPage(); $lines = []; // draw Product name $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140718)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to add custom attribute `warehouse_location` to Print on PDF
an bellow are the class to overwrite :

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php
```

update `draw()` Method in my case:

```
// draw Warehouse Location
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $this->getWarehouseLocation($item),
        'feed' => 240,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
```

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment/DefaultShipment.php
```

update `draw()` Method in my case:

```
// draw Warehouse Location
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $this->getWarehouseLocation($item),//This you will have to build 
         to get custom attribute mime case: 
         $this->loadMyProduct($item->getSku())->getCustomAttribute('warehouse_location')->getValue()
        'feed' => 240,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
```

```
 /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/AbstractItems.php
```

All of the above class are to overwrite method to PDF `draw()`

And the Bellow are to overwrite method to PDF `_drawHeader()`

update `_drawHeader()` Method both files:

```
$lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Warehouse Location'), 'feed' => 260]

/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php

/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

Hope it helps anyone!

Comment: What code did you use to show the attribute? Really need this but I can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @Stifboy I've update my answer.

Comment: In which file did you overrid headers and add the new column?

Comment: @zekia All the file I mentioned above you will need to overwrite  it's simple there are 2 methods to overwrite  `draw()` and `_drawHeader() `  just look out for them in those files!